# How to implement a session progress bar for parachain?

Tags: session

Polkadot has this:

[image]

And I hope I can have one for my parachain.
There is a session pallet on my parachain.
And the session period is readable from the constant.

So, I think this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/calculate-session-epoch-time-remaining/9946#9946) is a more generalized answer to this, specifically in Rust code and from within the Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the %, then you need to get the `sessionProgress` and the `sessionLength`:

```js
const progress = await api.derive.session.progress();
const total = progress.sessionLength;
const value = progress.sessionProgress;
console.log((value/total)*100);
```

Comment: I think this only works with solo babe + staking.