# Calculate Session/Epoch time remaining

Tags: rust

I've seen some websites display the estimated time remaining for the current session/epoch. Is there a Rust call for this? Is there a sample of that code?

Comment: I have already asked this but no good answer yet. https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/how-to-implement-a-session-progress-bar-for-parachain

Answer (score 1):

This entirely depends on the configuration of `pallet_session`.

First, this pallet itself does not enforce when sessions change. This is configured via [`ShoulEndSession`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/pallet_session/pallet/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.ShouldEndSession).

Second, there is also [`EstimateNextSessionRotation`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/pallet_session/pallet/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.NextSessionRotation) which you can always call to estimate [when the next session would rotate](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/traits/trait.EstimateNextSessionRotation.html#tymethod.estimate_next_session_rotation). This might be accurate or an estimate based on the former configuration.

For each trait, look at the list of implementors to see what options you have.

For example, if [`pallet-babe`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/pallet_babe/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#impl-EstimateNextSessionRotation%3C%3C%3C%3CT+as+Config%3E::Block+as+HeaderProvider%3E::HeaderT+as+Header%3E::Number%3E-for-Pallet%3CT%3E) is used as the former, then latter becomes an estimate, because `babe` uses a time-based session length, and if blocks are missed, then the session is essentially shortened in therms of block numbers.

Contrary, if [`PeriodicSession`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/pallet_session/struct.PeriodicSessions.html) is used, the session length is fixed in terms of block numbers and the estimate you get is also constant.